# Significant figures in a string format not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

So I want to print a simple line using data from a curve fit as such:

```
print('{}, {}, {}'.format(popt[0], popt[1], chi_squared))
```

which outputs:

```
 0.33274149918645834, 0.9185831984664338, 19.685835082519155
```

However as soon as I put a signifacant figures constraint on it it ouputs the first number multiples times as seen below and I am unsure why?

```
print('{0:.4f}, {0:.4f}, {0:.4f}'.format(popt[0], popt[1], chi_squared))
0.3327, 0.3327, 0.3327
```

Note: From this, I have got 2 answers. 1 how to fix the issue and 2 that I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0` before the `:` means to use argument number 0, which means they'll all be `popt[0]`. Just omit it:

```py
print('{:.4f}, {:.4f}, {:.4f}'.format(popt[0], popt[1], chi_squared))
```

Answer (score 1):

The zero in `"{0:<whatever>}"` means "print the 0th element". You don't have to pass the index of the elements to print explicitly, so you can simply write: `"{:.4f} {:.4f}".format(3.14159, 1.234567)`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are printing only `{0}` not others

```
print('{0:.4f}, {1:.4f}, {2:.4f}'.format(popt[0], popt[1], chi_squared))
```

I Love F-strings:

```
print(f"{popt[0]:.4f}, {popt[1]:.4f}, {chi_squared:.4f}")
```